# How can I group row values as columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

For a Table shown below

```
Animal        LiveIn
------        ------

Cat           land
fish          water
frog          land
frog          water
salamander    land
salamander    water
```

I need the result as below

```
Animal        Column1    Column2
------        -------    -------
cat           land       *null*
fish          water      *null*
frog          land       water
salamander    land       water
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you do this using `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select t.animal,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then livein end) as Column1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then livein end) as Column2
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by animal order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by t.animal;
```

Note that you have no way of expressing the ordering of the columns in the data -- SQL tables are inherently unordered.  The above chooses an arbitrary ordering.  If you have an `id` or `CreatedAt` column, then you can use that to specify the order.

Given that there is no ordering, the following also does an equivalent job:

```
select t.animal, min(t.LiveIn) as Column1,
       (case when min(t.LiveIn) <> max(t.LiveIn) then max(t.LiveIn) end) as Column2
from t
group by t.animal;
```

EDIT:

**SQL queries have to return a fixed number of columns.**  You can't have a query sometimes return three columns and sometimes four.  You can, however, adjust the query to return a larger number of columns, which may usually be `NULL`:

```
select t.animal, count(*) as NumLiveIn,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then livein end) as Column1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then livein end) as Column2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then livein end) as Column3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then livein end) as Column4
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by animal order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by t.animal;
```

In such a case, I would also add a column for the number of environments as well.

Comment: I don't know how much columns there will be. For example if there is another data a bird, which lives in sea, water, and sky a column3 required. How can I do that. Is it really impossible? What should I do if such requirement arose?

Comment: I'm not botherd about the order, its really unimportant for me! Thank you

Comment: please make this bold **SQL queries have to return a fixed number of columns. You can't have a query sometimes return three columns and sometimes four**

Answer (score 1):

Your code is confusing; what is a '-----' supposed to be showing me?

You have repeating values and your right to want to 'group' them.
Take a look at normalization since you seem to be involved with the schema level of a database and asking for [DDL code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language). 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

If the first two '------' are in fact two tables, I'd suggest the following rework of that schema.

```
Animal    Environment    Animal_Environment
------    ------         ------
id        id             animal_id
name      name           environment_id
```

With this we avoid repeating content within our database.
Also leads to simpler [DML queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) for that content.

Comment: ---- is nothing, but separating column name from values. And I think the table has a normalized structure. But my requirement might be a bit strange

Comment: They are not two tables. They are two columns. Thank you

Comment: @t-clausen I do, go fish.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but it is another way of solving it:

```
declare @t table(Animal varchar(10), LiveIn varchar(7))
insert @t values
('Cat','land'),('fish','water'),('frog','land'),
('frog','water'),('salamander','land'),('salamander','water')

select * from @t
PIVOT
(min([LiveIn])  
FOR Livein
in([land],[water])  
)AS p ORDER BY 1
```

Result:

```
Animal     land  Water
______________________
Cat        land  NULL
fish       NULL  water
frog       land  water
salamander land  water
```

Comment: Saying the table isn't a normalized one. See @wurde s answer. Someone upvoted him. I don't know what the mistake I did. I believe the table is normalized. Sometimes my requirement might be weird.